# “Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ebs

Iam newbie to EC2 and Ubuntu 11 (EC2 Free tier Ubuntu). I have made following commands.

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf6

sudo mkdir /db
sudo vim /etc/fstab 
/dev/xvdf6 /db ext4 noatime,noexec,nodiratime 0 0

sudo mount /dev/xvdf6 /db
fdisk  -l
```

I got following output. Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

```
Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/xvdf6: 6442 MB, 6442450944 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 783 cylinders, total 12582912 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvdf6 doesn't contain a valid partition table.
```

Answer (score 1):

The partition table is typically found on the disk itself, not on an individual partition.

So your partition tables should show up under /dev/xvda and /dev/xvdf, rather than on /dev/xvda1 and /dev/xvdf6.

From here, it looks like everything's fine.  Is there something else that makes you think it's not working correctly?